# Java: Replacing Boolean with a Char

Tags: java

Thank you for reading,

essentially I have a matrix of Boolean values and to print them I am using:

```
for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix[0].length; c++) {
        System.out.print(" " + matrix[r][c]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

I have tried and failed an obnoxious amount of times to replace the boolean values with chars, for example, replacing each false with the letter "x" and true with a "y", so that rather than a printed line read "false true true false true" it would read "x y x x y x"

-thank you for your time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use "? :" operator, follow this link http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html

```
for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < matrix[0].length; c++) {
    System.out.print(" " + (matrix[r][c] ? "y" : "x"));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the link and answer, both helped very much

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add an if statement in the loop like:

```
if(matrix[r][c]){
    System.out.print(" y");
} else {
    System.out.print(" x");
}
```

Comment: `println()` would put a new line for every "for", that must be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an inline if statement if it's just for output...

System.out.print((matrix[r][c]) ? "y" : "x");

m

Comment: I think you mean for the boolean expression to use a == sign.

Comment: Is this answer different from @NullCoder's answer?

Comment: I was just adding it at the same time! So it's the same.